# Refresh another jsp from a jsp in Web APP

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2

Creating a tiles based application in Struts2. There are 3 JSP. JSP A calling an action and refreshing JSP B. JSP C is in another tiles . Would like to update JSP C from JSP B with data from same action class.

Used jquery load function: `$('#a').load('article.html');`, but its not populating the fresh data, though getting refreshed JSP C.

Comment: Either this is a simple html (and a bit of JS) issue where you are not targeting the correct frame (or iframe) or there is a fundamental misunderstanding of what tiles does which comes to mind as you refer to tiles as if they are frames as a matter of fact you don't use the term "frame" even once although I think that is what you mean.  In either case we need some code along with an explanation of what it is supposed to be doing to figure this out.

Comment: Its simple. in jsp c, there is code                          <script> $('#a').load('jsp/article.jsp'); </script> ..jsp/article.jsp get updated or refreshed but data from action class is not loaded. So problem is from data loading perspective

Comment: expecting some ans from someone, thanks

Comment: We need code, we are not psychic.  How can we know if it is the action without seeing the action? Or at least what it is that you are getting when trying to call the action? Even the minimal snipit of html/js so we can see that there really is an id of "a"? Currently there are a million things that could be going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a code to redirect your parent window from your popup window, Use

```
window.opener.location="yourstrutsclassname";
```

for example

```
window.opener.location="welcome";
```